# How do I insert a background image on spectrum audio effect using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Based on [this](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/9697) beautiful answer, using **ffmpeg** I generate an **ahistogram** from an audio file with this command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -filter_complex \
"[0:a]ahistogram,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

[image: ahistogram]

I searched a lot on the internet but I can't find it, is it possible to set an image as background to this spectrum effect?

**UPDATE**

I tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/bg.jpg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[1:a]ahistogram=s=640x360:slide=scroll,colorkey=color=black:similarity=0.2[fg]; \
 [0:v][fg]overlay=shortest=1, format=yuv420p,scale=1280:-2[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

But the conversion speed is ridiculous slow.

Check the full log here:

```
ffmpeg version git-2017-01-22-f1214ad Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab --enable-libwavpack --enable-nvenc
  libavutil      55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
  libavcodec     57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
  libavformat    57. 63.100 / 57. 63.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 69.100 /  6. 69.100
  libavresample   3.  2.  0 /  3.  2.  0
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from 'bg.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8257 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 700x457 [SAR 1:1 DAR 700:457], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, mp3, from 'output2.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.46.100
  Duration: 00:00:21.84, start: 0.050113, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[swscaler @ 0x3ae8e60] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x3a5f7a0] using SAR=2438/2437
[libx264 @ 0x3a5f7a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x3a5f7a0] profile High, level 3.2
[libx264 @ 0x3a5f7a0] 264 - core 148 r2762 90a61ec - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.63.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x836 [SAR 7315:7312 DAR 700:457], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.75.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (mp3) -> ahistogram
  scale -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=28.0 Lsize=      18kB time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=1841.1kbits/s speed=0.0112x
```

Comment: Use this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34677320/5726027) with your filter.

Comment: @Mulvya I already tried it...but how to? This doesn't work `sudo ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i bg.jpg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4`

Comment: @Mulvya question updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ahistogram](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ahistogram) output contains an alpha channel, but it only affects the top part, so if you want to remove the black from the sonogram as well you'll need to use a keying filter such as [colorkey](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorkey):

[image]

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.jpg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[1:a]ahistogram=s=700x458:slide=scroll,colorkey=color=black:similarity=0.2[fg]; \
 [0:v]scale=iw:-2[bg]; \
 [bg][fg]overlay,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 1:a -shortest output.mp4
```

Your input is 700x457, but each dimension needs to be even, so scale filter is added to make it 700x458. ahistogram is also set to match this size, but it could be any arbitrary size.

Comment: I have a problem,  `height not divisible by 2 (700x457)` ...I tried edit this at the end `-shortest scale=1280:-2 output.mp4` without success

Comment: End the filter_complex like this: `format=yuv420p,scale=1280:-2[v]`

Comment: @Mulvya I tried but ...it starts and does nothing, the speed is below speed=0.0197x and I get this `deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly`

Comment: Show the full command and console output.

Comment: Bad timing for this answer on my part: got kicked off girlfriends computer while writing answer so she could use it, decided to submit unfinished so I could deal with it later, realized the existing ahistogram alpha is almost useless, updated answer, noticed Mulvya's comment using the typical key filter method... Anyway, as mentioned we will need to see the command and complete output to see what is wrong.

Comment: :) ops...I updated the question

Comment: @NineCattoRules I adjusted the answer to fit your particular inputs.